# I am making an api call using special character in string by taking input using UITextField but alamofire is automatically changing it to some code

Tags: ios, json, xcode, alamofire, swift4

Below mentioned are my parameters that I am using to make an api call

```
["password": "123456", "app_version": "1.0", "email": "problem’@swift.com", "device_token": "xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx", "device_type": "0"]
```

This is my response from backend

```
SUCCESS: {
message = "Data not valid";
postedData =     {
    "app_version" = "1.0";
    "device_token" = xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx;
    "device_type" = 0;
    email = "problem\U2019@swift.com";
    password = 123456;
};
status = 0;
"validation_errors" =     {
    email =         (
        "The email must be a valid email address."
    );
};
```

}

How should I remove this error.
This is the method with which I am making an api call using Alamofire

```
func emailRegistration( email : String, deviceID: String, deviceType: String, appVersion: String, password: String ){

    let urlString = BaseURL + "login"

    let params =
        [
            "email"              :  email,
            "device_token"       :  deviceID,
            "device_type"        :  deviceType,
            "app_version"        :  appVersion,
            "password"           :  password

            ]
    request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params).validate()

    Alamofire.request(urlString, method: .post, parameters: params).validate()
        .responseJSON { responseObject in
            print(responseObject)
            if responseObject.result.isSuccess {
                let resJson = responseObject.result.value
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NotifRequestSuccess.emailRegistration.rawValue), object: nil, userInfo: ["data": resJson])
            }
            if responseObject.result.isFailure {
                let error : Error = responseObject.result.error!
                NotificationCenter.default.post(name: Notification.Name(rawValue: NotifRequestError.emailRegistration.rawValue), object: responseObject, userInfo: nil)
                //debug//print(responseObject)
            }
    }
}
```

Comment: @Sulthan change is in email id. This is how my backend is receiving data. He is returning it to me as it is received.
Email is changing on its own when I am using special character

Comment: It looks like you are confusing what is actually there, with what the debugger displays.

Comment: My server is displaying error of invalid email. But for the same value via android it is working fine. I think there is an error at my end.

Answer (score 0):

Alamofire handles the strings correctly, escaping is part of JSON encoding. The JSON parser on your server is the one responsible for decoding.

From [JSON RFC](http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc4627.txt):

> 2.5. Strings
>
> The representation of strings is similar to conventions used in the C family of programming languages. A string begins and ends with quotation marks. All Unicode characters may be placed within the quotation marks except for the characters that must be escaped: quotation mark, reverse solidus, and the control characters (U+0000 through U+001F).
>
> **Any character may be escaped.**